# How do I retrieve actual worker answers to an mturk qualification test?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have a qualification test that I'd like to tune. If there are questions that are frequently missed, I will consider swapping them out or adding clarification.

The test is part of a Qualification Type. The worker is granted the test automatically after finishing with a score of the correct answers. My HITs require a minimum score on the qualification type to accept.

I don't see a view in the requester UI to see actual worker responses.

`GetQualificationsForQualificationType` only returns the status and value (score), though the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetQualificationsForQualificationTypeOperation.html) example response has answers. I've tried both java and WS calls. The sdk also has a `getQualificationRequests()` but it returns null for this qualification type. It returns an array of `QualificationRequest`. That class has `getTest()` and `getAnswer()` methods, but I don't see what it would return. It seems to me that qualification requests are only for those without tests, which are granted manually.

Anyone know a way to get the actuals? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format inline code so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to to do this if you're using an AnswerKey. There are two general strategies to get around this:

1. Do not set the qualification to be autogranted (or use an Answer Key). Then you can use the [GetQualificationRequests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetQualificationRequestsOperation.html) operation to see actual answers to individual questions. This may not work if you want to quickly qualify lots of workers, although you could write a script to poll for new requests and approve them based on the answers, while saving the qualification test answers locally. (They are no longer available from MTurk once the qualification has been granted.)
2. You can specify your qualification scores in such a way that each score uniquely identifies a pattern of answers. A simple way to do this is something like a three-question qualification test that scores each question separately by a factor of ten:

   a. Q1: correct = 1, incorrect = 0

   b. Q2: correct = 10, incorrect = 0

   c. Q3: correct = 100, incorrect = 0

Then scores of 1, 10, or 100 indicate 1 correct answer. 11, 101, or 110 indicate two correct answers, and scores of 111 indicate three correct answers. You can use the `In` comparator for your QualificationRequirements to then require, for example, that a worker has a score that is "In" 11, 101, 110, or 111 if you want them to have 2 or more correct answers.

There are obviously other scoring patterns that would similarly produce uniquely identifiable patterns of scores.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. With respect to the second option, very clever. But I have ten questions, four questions each ... you do the math. :>) So the first option is only open to me. I see the Test/Answer pair in the response example. Wish there was some value add, like sending a notification message as part of the [GrantQualification] (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GrantQualificationOperation.html). Seems that I can't send a notification/bonus until at least one HIT has been approved/rejected.

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation of option 1. Indeed, there is no option to contact workers until they've worked for you (it's a spam-prevention feature, albeit a sometimes frustrating one).